Visualising smooth structures on $R^4$
I’m looking for a simple example of an exotic smooth structure on the topological $R^4$.
I haven’t started Donaldson theory yet, so I don’t want to get into the nitty gritty of classification of these smooth structures. What I’m looking for for now is a construction of any one (of an uncountably infinite number of them) and an argument for why it’s inequivalent to the standard one.

I think you can find a Kirby diagram for this in Scorpan's book "Wild world of 4-manifolds."
